# RecyclerView: disable scroll if there is enough room for all items

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, android-recyclerview, disable

I have a huge `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`.
Sometimes there's a small number of items shown, and I need to disable scroll in this case. Scroll should be enabled only when there're too many items to be shown in a RecyclerView, so scroll is needed.

**Why?**
Because when a user clicks fast enough on items, the click listener is not triggered. User accidentally moves a RecyclerView a bit. Recycler's `onTouchListener` gets `EVENT_MOVE` and consumes the event.

I've tried to create custom GridLayoutManager with overridden `canScrollVertically()` method:

```
override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
    return super.canScrollVertically() && isScrollEnabled
}
```

I use this function to check if the RecyclerView is scrollable:

```
fun RecyclerView.isScrollableVertically(): Boolean {
    return computeVerticalScrollRange() > height
}
```

Then, I update isScrollEnable field:

```
val isScrollableVertically = items_list.isScrollableVertically()
(category_items_list.layoutManager as CustomGridLayoutManager).setScrollEnabled(isScrollableVertically)
```

But even when there are a lot of items to show, `items_list.isScrollableVertically()` returns false.

---

I'm trying a lot of things to disable scroll when there's enough room for all items, but I haven't found a proper way to do this for a day.
I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable scrolling before you check if view is scrollable.
Let see the implementation (java) of `computeVerticalScrollRange` method.

```
@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
    if (mLayout == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return mLayout.canScrollVertically() ? mLayout.computeVerticalScrollRange(mState) : 0;
}
```

Once you have disabled scrolling you will always get zero scroll range in your case. So I think this should help

```
// set 'isScrollEnabled' true    
(category_items_list.layoutManager as CustomGridLayoutManager).setScrollEnabled(true)

val isScrollableVertically = items_list.isScrollableVertically()
(category_items_list.layoutManager as CustomGridLayoutManager).setScrollEnabled(isScrollableVertically)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!
I'd like to add, that I update setScrollEnabled() after I update dataset for the RecyclerView this way: `recycler_view.post { /* scroll check here*/  }`

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me in Kotlin:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged( recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            // recyclerView.layoutManager!!.childCount) returns the number of visible items
            if (data.size <= recyclerView.layoutManager!!.childCount)
                recyclerView.stopScroll()
            }
})
```

This is called in the Activity/Fragment where you set the adapter for your recyclerView

EDIT: I've actually found that this condition works in more situations:

`if (recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange() < recyclerView.height)`